# Creating new columns with pandas .loc

Tags: pandas

My dataset looks like this:

```
ex = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'grp1': np.random.choice('A B'.split(), 20), 'grp2': np.random.choice([1, 2], 20), 'var1': np.random.rand(20), 'var2': np.random.randint(20)})
```

I want to create new columns with the next value within the groups, but the following code results in `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
ex[['next_var1', 'next_var2']] = ex.groupby(['grp1', 'grp2'])[['var1', 'var2']].shift(-1)
```

Therefore I tried to use `.loc`:

```
ex.loc[:, ['next_var1', 'next_var2']] = ex.groupby(['grp1', 'grp2'])[['var1', 'var2']].shift(-1)
```

However, it results in error:

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['next_var1', 'next_var2'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

What's wrong with the `.loc` usage?

Comment: I dont get warning with `ex[['next_var1', 'next_var2']] = ex.groupby(['grp1', 'grp2'])[['var1', 'var2']].shift(-1)` in Python 3.7.5

Answer (score 1):

With `loc` you can't create new columns. But you could do:

```py
ex['next_var1'], ex['next_var2'] = None, None

ex.loc[:, ['next_var1', 'next_var2']] = ex.groupby(['grp1', 'grp2'])[['var1', 'var2']].shift(-1).values
```

However you could also do:

```py
ex[['next_var1', 'next_var2']] = ex.groupby(['grp1', 'grp2'])[['var1', 'var2']].shift(-1)
```

Is what you tried but it works fine with python `3.7` and pandas `0.25`.